# Low slope roofing

Tags: materials, building-design, architecture

I’m having trouble finding resources that explain/describe type of low slope roof for cold weather. Is single ply or metal standing seam or BUR better if we are considering all cold weather related issues (snow, wind,etc)?

Answer (score 1):

Low slope roofing less the 3/12 especially in a harsh cold climate requires special considerations.

A good material is rubber sheets attached to the roof by burning and fusing a layer of tar, or self-adhesive peel-off materials.

Standing seam aluminium or galvanized sheathing is used too.

In areas prone to the snow water freezing over the eve and ponding behind an ice dam proper heating by means of appropriate electrical elements is built in at the eave to prevent back up ice water.

There are typical roofing details for these conditions employed in cold regions.